# 'react-native-fs' and 'react-native-fetch-blob' can not find the downloaded file

Tags: react-native-fetch-blob, react-native-fs

I user 'react-native-fs' and 'react-native-fetch-blob' to test file download in android emulator,
the console show me that the download is success, but I can not find where the file is in my emulator file system,or maybe it did not download successfully,can anybody tell me what to do,thanks

Comment: Which directory did you specify for download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function for Android with `react-native-fetch-blob`.

It works for me and the downloaded file will be placed in the downloads directory of the device/emulator.

```js
function downloadFile(url,fileName) {
  const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
  const downloads = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
  return config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
      useDownloadManager : true,
      notification : false,
      path:  downloads + '/' + fileName + '.pdf',
    }
  })
  .fetch('GET', url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer,the code is useful,if you do not mind, I want to ask some question more,if I just know that it is a  file but do not know what the document type is  that i going to download,what should i do to advance the code, and do you have code about download in ISO,I am not good at Englisth,hope you can understand what i said,THANKS!THANKS!THANKS!

Comment: First, the file type may be part of the download url. Second, I haven't tried iOS, but I think the code should be pretty much the same. Except for `DownloadDir` is only supported for Android, so you should use `DocumentDir`  instead, but then the file will be placed in the app's directory. At least, If the answer was helpful - You could up-vote it and mark as accepted.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your assistance

Comment: notification false does not work for me, still shows notification when file download finished. Do you know why?